# Google Analytics not tracking custom definitions?

Tags: google-analytics

My GA code is working properly, I can see traffic in real-time. For some reason, custom definitions are not being recorded.

Here's the relevant portion of my GA code:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'module-region', 'some city');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The definition is 100% set up with the correct name, and is set to active. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be using 'dimensionX' or 'metricY', not the name of the dimension/metric.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also try:

    ga('set',{'dimensionX':'module-region','metricX':'some city'});